# Getting specific column/row name instead of index when using idxmin or similar

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data list from a `csv` file containing column names and values in rows.

It's working pretty well, but now i still have one problem. I want to to have instead of the index number, the actual "Time" of the min "SkyT" (7.4 on 21:14:55.00).

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMVtI.png)

The following code gives me the indexnumber:

```
SkyT_Min_Time = df['SkyT'].idxmin()
```

The following code gives me the whole row:

```
SkyT_Min_Time = df.loc[df['SkyT'].idxmin()]
```

What do i need to only see the time value of that specific row , where the min SkyT value is present.

I expect to have the time value: `21:14:55.00` when the SkyT was 7.4, instead of index number 1

Comment: I think what you are looking for is: `df.iloc[df['SkyT'].idxmin()]['Time']`

Comment: Or if you just want the value of time on the **first** row: `df.loc[0, 'Time']`

Comment: My god! that did it ( first answer, your second option is also good, but that is if it always is the first row witch ofcourse isn't. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I will post it as answer :)

Comment: Is it possible to combine the following codes? So i could get the SkyT and Time value in one line. 

Code 1: `SkyT_Min = df['SkyT'].min().round(decimals=2)`             Code 2: `SkyT_Min_Time = df.iloc[df['SkyT'].idxmin()]['Time']`
Now i would use: `print (str(SkyT_Min_Time)+','+str(SkyT_Min))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
df.iloc[df['SkyT'].idxmin()]['Time']
```